# Autosys job not getting triggered every 15 minutes

Tags: autosys

I have defined the autosys box as below :

```
description="Trigger Hive refresh jobs"
date.conditions=date_conditions: 1
days.of.week=days_of_week: all
start.mins=start_mins:0,15,30,45
run.window=run_window:"02:00-23:59"
```

and the box's container has only the following command

```
command=/app/datarefresher/bin/refreshhivetables.sh
```

However, this task just runs at 02:00 and returns to the success state after one run.
It hasn't been triggered every 15 minutes as specified.